# Blow-Up over a Field

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that a function $\pi : \mathbb{C}_{*}^{n}\mapsto \mathbb{C}^{n}$ is bijective.
Where $\mathbb{C}_{*}^{n}$ is the explosion of  $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and is defined as

$\mathbb{C}_{*}^{n}:= \{(z,l) \in \mathbb{C}^{n}\times\mathbb{C}P^{n-1} | z \in l\}$

and $l$ is a line that pases through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

thank you, I am not very acquainted with the explosion over a field, can you explain me.

Comment: Your definition above is inherently circular.  You can't define an object using that object as part of its definition.  Also, what is the function $\pi$?

Comment: I am so sorry I´ve corrected :)

Comment: It is not bijective. It is usually called "blow-up" (in English).

Comment: Good but if we eliminate the preimage of the origin and if map to $\mathbb{C}^{n}-{0}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, $\pi(z,\ell)=z$? It's not bijective, at least for $n>1$.

$$\pi^{-1}(0)=\{(0,\ell)\mid\ell\in\mathbb CP^{n-1}\}$$

It is a bijection when excluding the $0\in \mathbb C^n$ and $\pi^{-1}(0)$ from the sets, because when $z\in\mathbb C^n\setminus\{0\}$, there is exactly one line $\ell$ through zero containing $z$.

Comment: Can you explain why there is exactly one line ℓ through zero containing z.

Comment: Two points determine a line. Perhaps that is the part that is confusing you. Here "line" means complex line, not Euclidean line, and the complex line between $0$ and $z$ is the set of points $\ell =\{az\mid:a\in \mathbb C\}$.

Comment: Do you mean a copy of $\mathbb{C}P^{1}$

Comment: No, that's the complex projective line. We're just talking line here - the affine image of $\mathbb C$ in $\mathbb C^n$. (Since the image contains zero, you can actually make it linear, not just affine...)

Comment: Ok, and can you explain in detail why $\pi$ is bijective please

Comment: It isn't bijective.

Comment: No this please: It is a bijection when excluding the 0∈ℂn and π−1(0) from the sets, because when z∈ℂn∖{0}, there is exactly one line ℓ through zero containing z.

Comment: it's bijective in that case because for any $z\in\mathbb C^n\setminus\{0\}$ then there is exactly one line $\ell$ containing $z$ and $0$, as I said.

Comment: Good, and this is because 1 line is determined by 2 points is´nt it ?

Comment: Can you prove your comment?

Comment: I'm not doing the entire problem, but if you can't prove that there is exactly one complex line containing $0$ and $z\neq 0$, I'm not sure what more help I can be.